# Azure AD Sync Error - Existing Admin Role Conflict

Tags: active-directory, azure, azure-activedirectory

I have an issue with our Azure AD tenant syncing with my domain AD account. When we set up the tenant (along with Office 365), we used a generic ID in the format user@company.onmicrosoft.com. My existing domain account is in the format user@company.com. This "role conflict error" shows up in Azure AD.

I should also add that I am having issues granting admin access to my on-prem account (despite it being able to log into any Office 365 services as Owner). For example, I cannot access any Sharepoint sites with the on-prem account unless I request access from any other synced account that has Owner privileges.

At this point, I would simply like to delete the onmicrosoft.com account from Azure, and merge the two accounts. However, I cannot delete that account, and I clearly do not want to delete the domain account, as it has needed functionality in our on-prem domain. What is the best way for me to remove this sync error, and fix this issue?

Comment: Did you implement Azure AD Connect and are syncing your Active Directory with Azure Active Directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some what of a common issue, below is the link to the fix.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/tshoot-connect-sync-errors#existing-admin-role-conflict

Comment: We have followed these instructions but the delete button in Azure AD for the Quarantined account is disabled. Any idea how to overcome that?

Comment: Make sure you have Remove the Azure AD account from all admin roles and that you are not logged in with that user.  These are the only 2 scenario I know of where user cannot be deleted.

Comment: We removed the Azure AD account from all admin roles, but were initially unable to delete the quarantined account thereafter. Ultimately, we were able to do so by running this command in PowerShell: Remove-AzureADUser -ObjectID user@domain.com. We also permanently deleted the object from Deleted Items.